# driver.fullscreen(), driver.dimensions() and driver.screenshotFull() does not work in headless mode

Tags: karate

I am trying to get the screen to be in full-screen size or at least get a screenshot of the whole screen during the test run but looks like Karate is not supporting that in headless mode. I can see the screen size change and screenshot taken in fullscreen when the test is run in non-headless mode.
Is there any extra change required?

Answer (score 0):

Quite likely this is not supported in headless mode. Think about it, there is no concept of screen or screen size.

You are most welcome to contribute code.